# Ubuntu 16.04 Server Installation with RaidZ2

Tags: server, system-installation, raid, zfs

I am interested in trying my hand at setting up a home server and have not been able to find conventional best practices relating to my noob question. That being whether or not I should A)install the OS on a separate drive following with the creation of the separate zpool or B)Boot from a live disk, setup the raidz in the live environment followed by installing the OS on that same array (if possible ? / no rebooting or otherwise). I cannot seem to locate pros and cons to each concept or if there is even a choice, meaning one is just a big no no... Is there a correct option? Is there any sort of reference you can point me to?

Option B in theory sounds better to me but I am not experienced and don't know what I am overlooking, please help...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the bootloader, Grub, by default includes ZFS modules in it's image. So it should work when you boot from the EFI system partition into the zpool. (I assume you have a UEFI capable x64 server.) Apart from that I have no experience with such setups and relying on a dkms managed kernel module could get you into trouble. I assume you could always fix issues from a live disk with chroot similar to reinstalling Grub, but I'm not this kind of relaxed when one of my machines don't play nice. So I'd recommend to have at least an ext4 root FS somewhere as a backup.

Comment: It is an older mboard without UEFI, just BIOS. But If its in grub loader I don't suspect that would be a problem. I'll test once my HD's come in...Good idea on the root backup

Answer (score 1):

My experience with ZFS mainly is based on BSD (FreeNAS etc.). In those installations, the OS is usually installed on a different small disk (even USB-pendrive), to have all the disk space for your zpool (with RAIDZ2 you should have a lot of disks of same size). So the zpool is even portable between different OS (I have successfully ported one zpool, between FreeNAS, Nas4Free and ZFSonLinux without problems).

You may install the OS on a small partition of a SSD and have the rest of that as SLOG device for the zpool as recommended for peformance reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about the portability  aspect that makes me want to install the OS separate.